# Displaying live location data from server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an iPhone app which should display the location of unlimited number of users on a map.

The way I want to do it is sending a request to the server every 5-8 seconds and get the best location of the users.
Also every user sends his location automatically every 5-8 seconds to the server.

Is there another or more valuable way for doing this?

Comment: you can do like usin NSTimer for sending Server reqest for each5-8 second and reload data at end of NSTimer method..

Comment: That's what I'm planning to do, but I'm asking if there's another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSTimer` for this task, this is the best way,

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(sendYourRequest:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```